# Decreasing value of minimum int results in maximum int

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, int

I'm currently reading through C# 4.0 In A Nutshell, and in chapter 2 it states that if an int object has a value of `int.MinValue` (-2147483648) and the value is decreased, as the value cannot go any lower, it goes to the highest value, `int.MaxValue` (2147483647):

```
int a = int.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine(a); //-2147483648
a = a-1;
Console.WriteLine(a); //-2147483648
Console.WriteLine (a == int.MaxValue);  // True
```

The book then goes on to mention how you can protect from this happening using `checked`.

However, I'm wondering why this is possible? Surely this could cause a lot of issues if its not protected with `checked`?

Is it not a bit of a flaw in the design? Why would anyone want a minimum value to become a maximum value?

---

Furthermore, I've noticed VB.NET will throw an 'Arithmetic overflow' instead of letting this happen:

```
Dim a As Integer
a = Integer.MaxValue
a = a + 1
Response.Write(a) 'Arithmetic overflow exception here
```

Comment: in c#, if you try `int a = int.MinValue -1;` will return Error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is desired behaviour. Other times, it simply isn't necessary to deal with and check for overflows, as they slow down program execution. Take a game drawing unbound (FPS). At 1000FPS, a small 1ms extra check could have a significant affect on framerate. Other times, it may be expected execution (I've only seen one use of this to date) - it flows on from what happens in C#'s ancestor - C++ and C.

Also, please note that the default behaviour (`checked` or `unchecked`) varies between configurations and environments:

> If neither checked nor unchecked is used, a constant expression uses
>   the default overflow checking at compile time, which is checked.
>   Otherwise, if the expression is non-constant, the run-time overflow
>   checking depends on other factors such as compiler options and
>   environment configuration.

Since the code you posted is non-constant (and also due to various environment variables), no checking for overflows is performed.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of language design - why this happens has to do with the binary representation of numbers. In .NET this is done with [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), hence the overflow issue.

The designers of VB.NET have decided to not allow such overflow/underflow issues.

The designers of C# have decided to leave control to the programmer.

Comment: Is it not a bit of a flaw in the design? Why would anyone want a minimum value to become a maximum value?

Comment: @Curt - flaw? It is a design decision. It was done on purpose. A checked context is much slower than a non checked one, so it is a matter of deciding which is more important. And as the `checked` context is part of the design, this become a decision by the developer, it's not like it wasn't considered at all.

Comment: Okay I see thanks, that makes a lot more sense to me now. So VB.NET has a built in `checked` for every value change to an `int` type, whereas C# has better performance as this check is left up to the decision of the developer, and whether its required in each case?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your programm automatically check overflow: right click on project file,
select Build, than select Advanced button in right bottom corner. In the opened window check Check Arithmetical Overflow checkbutton.